# Create callback in Ionic 2 for Observable.timer

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a **Observable.timer** function that creates a countdown and I want to call a specific function called **endTimer()** when the timer has ended inside my @Component without using  setTimeout(). I can check the value of **counter == 0** in the view but how do I check in the @Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'

//imported pipes
import {FormatTimer} from '../../pipes/formattimer';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-livegame',
  templateUrl: 'livegame.html',
  pipes: [FormatTimer]
})
export class LivegamePage {

  gamesData: any;
  countDown: any;
  counter = 1*60;
  tick = 1000;

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage) {
    //setTimeout(function(){ endTimer(); }, 300000);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getCurrentGame();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
      .take(this.counter)
      .map(() => --this.counter);
  }

  endTimer() {
     console.log('ended');
  }

}
```

> `<div *ngIf="counter == 0">the timer has ended </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you **subscribing** to it somewhere? on the template with 'async' pipe or so? If not, you have to subscribe to it. For the same reason, the variable 'this.counter' will never reach 0.

If you are already subscribing to it on the template with async Pipe, you can use the operator finally:

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
       .take(this.counter)
       .map(() => --this.counter)
       .finally(() => this.endTimer())
  }
```

if you are not subscribing to it on the template, you can subscribe like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
       .take(this.counter)
       .map(() => --this.counter)
       .finally(() => this.endTimer())
       .share() // Avoid multiple side effect if multiple subscribers

     this.countDown.subscribe(() => { /* do nothing */})
  }
```

Hope this helps.